# QGIS - mbtiles export in core functionality?

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

Seems like exporting mbtiles is a fairly common need, and it seems like there is a patchwork of various third-party pieces of code and old or partially-integrated plugins to address the need with various levels of success and quality - but they are all obscure and difficult and not-quite-there despite the developer's best efforts...  has the idea of building mbtiles export functionality into the qgis core ever come up?

Comment: You can check if it's on [the roadmap](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/roadmap) or it there's a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues). If someone's working on it, there's usually a link from the feature request to the project on github or a fundraising site.

Comment: Have you tried [Qtiles3?](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles3/)

Answer (score 3):

it is part of the core 3x version at least you simply  right click save as MBTILES or  it's also available via Raster Menu, Conversion, Translate. It's using GDAL_Translate you can see the commands it's issuing.  One thing you must know is that GDAL does not do zoom levels it will build tiles for lowest zoom level and then you must use gdaladdo to build overview zoom levels.  GDAL2Tiles_Parallel.py is much faster and uses all your CPU cores I recommend downloading that python script.By Reinventing Geospatial you can find it in their gitlab https://gitlab.com/GitLabRGI/erdc/geopackage-python also check out  https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp